# Best wood for wood post base?

Tags: wood, deck, porch

The bottom of my porch post is rotten. I will be painting the new wood. What kind of wood would be best for this?

[image]

Comment: Pressure treated without incising.

Comment: And it doesn't matter what kind of wood as long as it is pressure treated?

Comment: @junta you'll be hard pressed to find any pressure treated lumber that _isn't_ SPF (Spruce-Fir-Pine, i.e. whatever was cheap on the day they were buying). Something to consider: It looks like a concrete porch, and it's in a high moisture area with the plants and the down spout. You may want to get PVC trim. It's sold in standard dimensional trim sizes, it looks (more or less) like wood, and it cuts and nails with normal wood-working tools. However, it's 100% PVC so it'll never rot. It even comes (by default) in white, so you might not even have to paint it.

Comment: The trim is rotten, but you don't yet know if the post itself is rotten. Remove the trim and see what you have.

Comment: Redwood/cedar/synthetic. Backprime (ie, paint all the surfaces) and hold the bottom off the stone by a good 1/4"